# Browser support PNG transparency

Tags: transparency, browser-support

Is IE6 the only browser that doesn't support PNG transparency?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/pngopacity/

> It turns out that most of the latest
>   versions of the major browsers fully
>   support alpha transparency with PNG –
>   namely, Netscape 6, Opera 6, and
>   recently-released Mozilla 1, all on
>   Windows; and, for the Mac, Internet
>   Explorer 5, Netscape 6, Opera 5,
>   Mozilla 1, OmniWeb 3.1, and ICab 1.9.
>   Incredibly, PNG even works on Opera 6
>   for Linux, on WebTV, and on Sega
>   Dreamcast.
>
> IE5.5+/Win, bless its heart, will, in
>   fact, display a PNG, but it doesn’t
>   natively support alpha transparency.
>   In IE5.5+/Win, the transparent area of
>   your PNG will display at 100% opacity
>   – that is, it won’t be transparent at
>   all.

Answer (score 6):

IE 5.5 and IE 6 don't correctly display a PNG image, they don't support alpha transparency. This can be fixed with [this *hack*](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/). I use it on all my sites and works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure that IE5 doesn't either.

Comment: I meant on browsers that are higher than IE6 ^_^

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the only commonly used browser that doesn't support PNG transparency.

Obviously other older browsers such as Netscape 3, IE5 et al also lack support for this but I'm assuming your question is about browsers in every day use.